# Praat fixed$ function

Tags: praat

I am writing a praat script to segment a file, but also add padded boundaries. When I use the following line:

```
start = 9.17
paddedStart = fixed$(start - 0.200, 3)
```

I get the error

`"Found a string expression instead of a numeric expression"`

but if I try

`paddedStart = fixed$(number(start), 3)`

I get the error

`"The function "number" requires a string, not a number."`

How can I used the `fixed$` function to limit the number of decimal places in a number?

Comment: At the level of numeric computation, I don't think you can control Praat's precision by defining the limit on floating point. Your question is about converting a floating point number to a character string, as you figured out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Praat questions may sometimes be linguistics-related but this one just seems like a general programming language question applied to specifically Praat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. `fixed$` creates a **string**, not a number. So, if you use the `number` function, a number is returned. Ex: `number(fixed$(start - 0.200, 3))`

Comment: Please mark your own answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

fixed$ takes only 2 arguments, so you should realise your calculations outside the function.

The variable start has only 2 digits after the decimal point, so it is meaningless to propose 3 digits.

Try this:

---

start = 9.17

start2 = start - 0.2

paddedStart = fixed$(start2, 1)

paddedStart2 = number(paddedStart)

---

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this, and it didn't work. The problem is that `fixed$` returns a string.

Comment: You just have to change your string in number by using the function number(): paddedStart2 = number(paddedStart).